# Semi-transparent splash screen bevel

Tags: .net, wpf, splash-screen

A [Zune](http://www.zune.net) splash screen:

[image: zune splash screen]

has a square, semi-transparent border around splash screen image.

How can one get such semi-transparent border on **.net** app's splash screen?

Comment: It is just plain glass.  Google 'dwmextendframeintoclientarea'.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be how they have achieved it. Thank you. The .net approach, using the same API, but from managed code is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748975(VS.100).aspx

Comment: @Hans, can you put your comment and an answer, so I can mark it as a correct one? I think this is important for anyone who may find this question upon their search.

Comment: Why don't you post the code?  The pinvoke will be useful to somebody else.  Mark your post as the answer.

Comment: @HansPassant, was reviewing my questions an noticed - the corners on the picture above are too sharp to be just the normal aeroglass extended into a window just a bit. It is probably something else, do you agree?

Comment: It is a borderless window, thus sharp corners and no shadow.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps for a partly transparent WPF splashscreen:

1) Create a PNG with the desired semi-transparent parts
2) In your SplashScreen.xaml (or whatever the name of it), do this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="MyPngImagePath" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you want to use a regular image with no transparency and put a semi-transparent border around it, simply put the Image in the XAML above into a `<Border />` with `BorderBrush` set to a semi-transparent color (i.e: a color like `#AABBBBBB` where AA defines transparency)

Answer (score 0):

Look at Transparency Properties on .NET forms

On your image border put this square in a specific color, then use the Transparency property to  apply a MaskColor

Once i found a code exemple taht takes a PNG image and apply the transparency component on the form...
This code project tutorial can help:

[Transparency Tutorial with C# - Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/CsTranspTutorial1.aspx)

[Transparency Tutorial with C# - Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/CsTranspTutorial2.aspx)

[Transparency Tutorial with C# - Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/CsTranspTutorial3.aspx)

Comment: I post ALL as code becaus the aswer box was sayin that i have non formated code on my aswer ¬¬. Sory by this.